# Unity UI components have only missing scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with native Unity components. In my project all UI objects are getting initialized with missing scripts. All Event System components, everything connected with UI.

New empty project works fine, which leads me to the idea, that something is wrong with my current project.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Did you accidentally delete the Library/metadata folder?

Comment: No, I guess in this case untiy will just reimport all assets. I am not sure. But anyway - no. I didn't delete anything.

Comment: Yeah, but usually, I've seen this happen in one of two cases. (a) deleted metadata folder. (b) UnityEngine.UI missing from project reference

Comment: Thanks. Both are at the right places :(

Comment: Is it possible to try copying all your assets into a new project, just as a debugging step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Unity hasn't imported UI to your project. I had this problem too. Close your project. Just delete temp and library folder and reopen project. this time unity will import this UI library.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But it doesn't look like a good solution to me if it will happen again. Its a pretty big project and reimporting all the assets takes really long time. Are there any other options? And why did it happen? It worked fine until yesterday morning. Some Unity bug?

Comment: No , it won't happen again. Unity didn't delete UI library, it was never imported. But now it is imported, and there is no problem. this is just a kind of bug. I don't know why but I had this problem my first project after I installed Unity 5. Actually it was also my first project which I used UI library. But really I dont know for what it happens.

Comment: As I said, it worked fine WITH ui till yesterday morning. I used event system and lots of ui elements. Only yesterday after opening the project it showed that all scripts are missing. I don't think that it was never imported, it doesn't look like it.

Comment: Yeah may be, as I said I don't know what is the problem really. But it didn't happen again after I reimport UI library.